# MSDN examples for UVC

Tags: c++, uvc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/stream/sample-application-for-uvc-extension-units

I am trying to find the source code the this example.

where can I find the implementation of

```
hr = FindExtensionNode(pKsTopologyInfo,
     GUID_EXTENSION_UNIT_DESCRIPTOR,
     &dwExtensionNode);
  if (FAILED(hr))
  {
        printf("Unable to find extension node : %x\n", hr);
 goto errExit;
  }
```

I am trying to control these

```
•   Exposure control:
    GUID: C9606CCB-594C-4D25-AF47-CCC496435995
    Node: 2
    Control: 3
    Value size: 4 bytes

•   Auto Exposure control:
    GUID: C9606CCB-594C-4D25-AF47-CCC496435995
    Node: 2
    Control: 11
    Value size: 1 byte
```

Comment: Did you read _"...The content and sample code in this topic is outdated and currently unsupported. It may not work with the current driver development toolchain...."_ from the link ?

Comment: Also _"...The “FindExtensionNode” is not a library function; you have to write your
own. At the end of this answer __I have included my code for the function__...."_ https://microsoft.public.development.device.drivers.narkive.com/h3fHndsf/usb-video-class-extension-unit

Comment: @RichardCritten I have read it but still, I am wondering what to do in order to use Extension units.. where is the updated code.